# How to I set panning in Howler JS 2.0?

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, howler.js

I am using howler js in a new project, and cannot get left/right pan to work. The document says to use the pos() function, and set the x value to -1000 - +1000.  My code:

```
howl.pos(-1000,0,0) for pan left
howl.post(1000,0,0) for pan right
```

But I do not hear a difference at all.  I have tested in Chrome, Safari, and Firefox.

[Howler JS 2.0 Documentation](https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js/tree/2.0)

Comment: Those are the upper limits, which means that going all the way to -1000 and 1000 will make your audio so incredibly distant that it probably won't be audible. Try setting closer to a range of -1 to -10 and 1 to 10 and you'll probably have better results.

Comment: Thanks James.  I think that's what I am after.  I wanted to be able to make the right channel 100% and the left channel 0% (pan right), for example.  How do I accomplish that?

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

```
howl.stereo(-1) for pan left 100%
howl.stereo(1) for pan right 100%
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Howler is abstracting the Web Audio API [PannerNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PannerNode) which requires you to do the needed [math to create an equal power panning effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14378305/how-to-create-very-basic-left-right-equal-power-panning-with-createpanner). The Web audio API when used directly now has a [StereoPannerNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/StereoPannerNode) that does exactly what you want. It looks like Howler needs to update their library.